# Shortcut don't 'react' on Fn button

Tags: lenovo, shortcuts

I try to add my custom shortcut using Fn key. My all shortcut work perfectly after install, but brightness adjust don't work.
I try to get 'code' of key using `xev` but it not apper.
Device: Lenovo IdeaPad-5
System: Ubuntu 22.04.1
Graphic: Wayland

Comment: just update core will fix it (i try on Arch)

Answer (score 0):

On many laptops, the `Fn` key is used internally by the keyboard microcontroller to control how it will react to the `F1`-`F99` keys, and is NOT sent to the computer, similar to the `Shift Lock` key.

That's why `xev` doesn't see it, and your quest to assign a shortcut to the `Fn` key is doomed.

Comment: I understand, what can i do with it?